# .htaccess for MVC gives 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am new to making a MVC application, although I have some experience with Laravel, I do know a few things about it.

Right now I try to make my own MVC application, but the problem is, that when I create my `.htaccess` file in the public directory, I get an Internal server error. Can someone help me out?

My environment is Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) Server at localhost Port 80.

.htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /public

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Url to rewrite is: http://localhost/public/

Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** I just don't get it... After the suggestion of @NicoHaase, I have looked in the errorlog which is printing this:

> Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a
>   module not included in the server configuration

What is wrong with the rule "RewriteEngine On"?

Comment: What does your server's error log contain?

Comment: @NicoHaase Thanks for your comment! I have posted the error log in mij edit

Answer (score 1):

I have found the problem and solved it! I should have enabled my mod_rewrite by running the command "a2enmod rewrite" in my apache server and then restart the server.

It is fixed now!